# filter pandas DataFrame column list with other list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input DataFrame :

```
data = { "id" : ['[1,2]','[2,4]','[4,3]'],
             "name" : ['a','b','c'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

filterstr = [1,2]
```

Expected Output:

```
id     name
[1,2]   a      
[2,4]   b
```

Tried Code  :
`df1 = df[df.id.map(lambda x: np.isin(np.array(x), [[ str([i]) for i in filter]]).all())]`

This works for single value in id column but not for two values like '[1,2]'
Not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: The type of `id` column is a list or a string representation of a list? In the last case, is it safe to convert it as a list? Your `filterstr` is a list?

Comment: Not sure to understand, do you want partial or exact match? If exact why "b" is selected? If partial why "c" not selected (contains "2")?

Comment: my mistake , need partial match ..corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking exactly what you've given:

```
data = { "id" : ['[1,2]','[2,4]','[4,3]'],
             "name" : ['a','b','c'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

filterstr = [1,2]
```

I do:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(eval) # Convert from string to list.
output = df[df.id.map(lambda id: any(x for x in id if x in filterstr))]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
       id name
0  [1, 2]    a
1  [2, 4]    b
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating DF:

```
data = { "id" : [[1,2],[2,4],[4,3]], #REMOVE STRING AROUND []!!!
         "name" : ['a','b','c'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Result:

| index | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1,2 | a |
| 1 | 2,4 | b |
| 2 | 4,3 | c |

Then let's create a variable which will be our "boolean" **filter**:

```
reg = [1,2]
filter = df.id.apply(lambda x: any(i for i in x if i in reg))
```

Intermediate result:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Then select only "**True**" values:

```
df = df[filter]
df
```

Final result:

| index | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1,2 | a |
| 1 | 2,4 | b |